# Why X is relying on software instead of hardware with "nomodeset" kernel parameter for 3D acceleration?

Tags: xubuntu, 14.04, suspend, 3d, nomodeset

My laptop is an ASUS K55N with AMD A8-4500M Trinity APU and integrated Radeon HD 7640G. Yesterday I tried at least 8 live sessions from different distros (slackware based, gentoo based, arch based, debian based, ubuntu based) with the same results: backlight off after suspend.

What I've done so far that works better is to modify `/etc/default/grub` to:

```
GRUB_CMD_LINE_DEFAULT="nomodeset acpi_osi="
```

My workaround works but only because Xfce does not rely on 3D acceleration. If you try to change to a compositor that relies on 3D acceleration you'll get into trouble with high temperatures. So, if you want to use a pretty and modern desktop like KDE, GNOME, Cinnamon, Unity or Pantheon you are going to need 3D acceleration hence you can't use `nomodeset` hence you can't Suspend.

On the other hand, what I know about nomodeset is it should not kill 3D hardware acceleration after X kicks in.

The question is:

Why X is relying on software instead of hardware with `nomodeset` kernel parameter for 3D acceleration?

More information at: [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/1283938)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the X.org guys have ripped out XAA (X Acceleration), and are requiring DRI (/dev/dri/card0) to be available to render anything other than via llvmpipe (software rendering). When you load with nomodeset and acpi_osi=, you are preventing your card from being detected by DRI.  You may be able to log in, but it will very sluggish.

You can test what you are running by typing

```
glxinfo | less
```

And searching for Gallium 3D and/or llvmpipe.

The glxinfo program may require the mesa-utils package, just

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

To install if needed.